# setting the default value on a Select2 dropdown

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

I have declared a select2 dropdown on an MVC form in the following way:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ContactGroup.Id, Model.ContactGroupSelectList, "Select a Contact Group")
```

This populates and displays the initial value as expected. On a change event of another dropdown, I want to set the above back to it's default value (by default, I mean the place holder value "Select a Contact Group" so it's not part of the actual data). if I do either of the following it sets the value back to an empty string (blank). I've looked all over the internet but have had no luck finding a solution:   `$('#ContactGroup_Id').select2("val", "Select a Contact Group");
$('#ContactGroup_Id').select2("val", "0");`

Comment: post the code of jquery change event and another drop down.

Comment: The change event of the other dropdown IS calling the above.It's the above that's the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following sets the first (`null`) option as selected

```
$('#ContactGroup_Id').select2("val", "", "placeholder", "Select a Contact Group");
```

Comment: How could that possible set it back to the initial value id the initial value is not the first `null` option

Comment: @StephenMuecke No Idea, but it works so dont know why you've voted the answer down

Comment: If the initial selected option based on the value of `ContactGroup.Id` is (say) the 5th option in the list, this will re-select the first one, not the 5th one

Comment: All I'm trying to do at this point is reset the value to effectively empty as I dont want to confuse the user, as the form for these in this instance doesn't have any labels the placeholder reminds theuser what this dropdown is for

Comment: Your question states _set the above back to it's default value_ (and the default value of a select is the initial value - not the first (`null`) option). Perhaps you just got your terminology wrong?

Comment: And if that is the case, edit your question to make it clear what you really want to do (and I will delete this downvote)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have made the question clearer. Please read.

Answer (score 0):

**Controller Action:**

```
public ActionResult Shop()
{
    var fruits = new List<object>();
    var vegetables = new List<object>();

    fruits.Add(new { ID = 0, Name = "Banana" });
    fruits.Add(new { ID = 1, Name = "Mango" });

    vegetables.Add(new { ID = 0, Name = "Spinach" });
    vegetables.Add(new { ID = 1, Name = "Potatoes" });

    ViewBag.Fruits = new SelectList(fruits, "ID", "Name");
    ViewBag.Vegetables = new SelectList(vegetables, "ID", "Name");

    return View();
}
```

**View:**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#Vegetables").change(function () {
            //When a value is changed in the Vegetables drop down set the Fruits dropdown to "Select a fruit"
            $("#Fruits").val($("#Fruits option:first").val());
        });
    });
</script>
@Html.DropDownList("Fruits", ViewBag.Fruits as SelectList, "Select a fruit")
@Html.DropDownList("Vegetables", ViewBag.Vegetables as SelectList)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#select2List").val("");
$("#select2List").select2().select2("val", "", "placeholder", "--select--");
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for your answer. Rather than just posting a block of code, can you give a short explanation to what the issue is you solved and how you solved it? This will help people who find this question in the future to better understand the issue and how to deal with it.

Answer (score -1):

lets say you want the default value to be 0, in javascript try:

```
$('#ContactGroup_Id').val('0');
```

reply if it doesn't work

Comment: this one doesn't work. There's something different when using a Select2 control